# How to check for a match in a JSON response using only half of a string

Tags: json, date, iteration

I have a JSON response as follows:

```
 {  
       "status":"success",
       "data":[  
          {  
             "id":"2630",
             "client_id":"1",
             "date":"2017-04-26 18:21:11",
             "latitude":"0.00000000",
             "longitude":"0.00000000"
          },
          {  
             "id":"2632",
             "client_id":"2",
             "date":"2017-04-26 18:25:57",
             "latitude":"0.00000000",
             "longitude":"0.00000000"
          },
          {  
             "id":"2635",
             "client_id":"1",
             "date":"2017-04-26 18:22:20",
             "latitude":"0.00000000",
             "longitude":"0.00000000"
          },
          {  
             "id":"2635",
             "client_id":"1",
             "date":"2017-04-23 18:21:23",
             "latitude":"0.00000000",
             "longitude":"0.00000000"
          },
          {  
             "id":"2635",
             "client_id":"2",
             "date":"2017-04-21 18:18:21",
             "latitude":"0.00000000",
             "longitude":"0.00000000"
          }
       ]
    }
```

I would like to check each entry of the 'data' key, and extract all of those that match the date of today's date (**Assuming today's date is 2017-04-26**) and add them to a separate array.

I have a date object that i create using

```
var isoDate = new Date().toISOString();
var isoShort = isoDate.slice(0,10);
```

Please assume that **isoShort = "2017-04-26"** and not actually today's date that would be generated by the date constructor.

My question is, how can i compare this isoShort value with the dates in the JSON response? The date values in the JSON have HH:MM:SS format added, i only need to compare with the first bit so == won't work.

Comment: this is c# isnt??

Comment: JavaScript, sorry forgot to add.

Comment: You'll have to scan every `"date"` entry and compare the dates. You can either convert them to dates and see if the difference is non-negative but smaller than 1 day, or, depending on your input, just see if they start with the right substring.